# How retrieve specific duplicate array values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, unique

```
$array = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'upline' => 0
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Jerry Maxwell',
    'upline' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'Roseann Solano',
    'upline' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'Joshua Doe',
    'upline' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 5,
    'name' => 'Ford Maxwell',
    'upline' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 6,
    'name' => 'Ryan Solano',
    'upline' => 1
),
array(
    'id' =>7,
    'name' => 'John Mayer',
    'upline' => 3
),
```

);
I want to make a function like:

```
function get_downline($userid,$users_array){
}
```

Then i want to return an array of all the user's upline key with the value as $userid. I hope anyone can help. Please please...

Comment: You have no dupes in your sample? What makes for a dupe?

Comment: I want retrieve an array of users with the same upline values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need do search thru yours array by $id:

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
   $user_id = $value["id"];
   $userName = $value["name"];
   $some_key++;

   $users_array[$user_id] = array("name" => $userName, "upline" => '1');
}

function get_downline($user_id, $users_array){
     foreach($users_array as $key => $value)
     {
         if($key == $user_id)
         {
              echo $value["name"];
              ...do something else.....
         }
     }
}
```

or to search by 'upline':

```
function get_downline($search_upline, $users_array){
         foreach($users_array as $key => $value)
         {
             $user_upline = $value["upline"];
             if($user_upline == $search_upline)
             {
                  echo $value["name"];
                  ...do something else.....
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with a simple loop, but let's use this opportunity to demonstrate PHP 5.3 anonymous functions:

```
function get_downline($id, array $array) {
    return array_filter($array, function ($i) use ($id) { return $i['upline'] == $id; });
}
```

BTW, I have no idea if this is what you want, since your question isn't very clear.

Comment: basicall i just want to retrieve an array of all users with the value '1' for their upline key.

Comment: If that's based on the `$id` parameter for this function, then the above does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

**Code :**

```
function get_downline($userid,$users_array) 
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($users_array as $user)
    {
        if ($user['id']==$userid)
            $result[] = $user['upline'];
    }
    return result;
}
?>
```

**Example Usage :**

```
get_downline(4,$array);
```